# add and remove input field function

Tags: javascript, php, html

1. I have a problem with the deleting function, is my code wrong or something? The add function is working fine though..........
2. plus how to insert the data from the added input field into the
   database?

   ```
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function() 
   {
       var max_fields      = 25; 
       var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); 
       var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); 

       var x = 1; //initial text box count
       $(add_button).click(function(e){ 
           e.preventDefault();
           if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
               x++; //text box increment
              $(wrapper).append('<div><label for="no_telefon">No.Telefon: </label><input type="text" name="no_telefon[]" id="no_telefon[]" class="required input_field"><label for="lokasi[]">Lokasi: </label><input type="text" name="lokasi[]" id="lokasi[]"  class="required input_field"><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
           }
       });

       $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
           e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
       })
   });

   </script>
   ```

   ```
                                   <div class="input_fields_wrap">
                                   <h3 class="add_field_button"><a href="#">Add More Fields</a></h3>  



                                   <label for="no_telefon">No.Telefon:</label> <input type="text"  id="no_telefon" name="no_telefon" class="required input_field" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'')" required/> 
                                   <label for="lokasi">Lokasi:</label> <input type="text" id="lokasi" name="lokasi" class="required input_field" required/>


                                   </div>




                                   </fieldset>
   ```

the sql.......

```
<?php
require("dbase.php"); 

if ($_POST) {

    $id_akaun           = isset($_POST['id_akaun'])         ? $_POST['id_akaun'] : '';
    $daerah             = isset($_POST['daerah'])           ? $_POST['daerah'] : '';
    $kategori_akaun     = isset($_POST['kategori_akaun'])   ? $_POST['kategori_akaun'] : '';
    $bahagian           = isset($_POST['bahagian'])         ? $_POST['bahagian'] : '';
    $jenis              = isset($_POST['jenis'])            ? $_POST['jenis'] : '';
    $no_telefon         = isset($_POST['no_telefon'])       ? $_POST['no_telefon'] : '';
    $lokasi             = isset($_POST['lokasi'])           ? $_POST['lokasi'] : '';
    $id                 = isset($_POST['id'])               ? $_POST['id'] : '';


    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO maklumat_akaun VALUES ('', '$id_akaun' , '$daerah' , '$kategori_akaun' , '$bahagian' )");
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO detail_akaun VALUES   ('', '$jenis' , '$no_telefon' , '$lokasi', '".mysql_insert_id()."' )");





    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('AKAUN BERJAYA DIDAFTARKAN')</script> ";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='lamanutama.php'</script>";
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent of the clicked button is not `div` so this expession `$(this).parent('div').remove();` does nothing. Use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method instead:

```
$('fieldset').on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('div').remove();
    x--;
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/11jdyrdf/

Comment: BUT, how to insert the data from the added field into the database?it only takes the first data @dfsq

Comment: @itsfawwaz Change names of the inputs to `name="no_telefon[]"`. You should get array then.

Comment: the how can i see data? @dfsq

Comment: Check in your server script where you send request `$_POST['no_telefon']`.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't put closing tag of label

Make your code perfect you have written wrong code..

Replace your appending code with this one

and then parent() will work

```
$(wrapper).append('<div><label for="no_telefon">No.Telefon: </label><input type="text" name="no_telefon[]" id="no_telefon[]" class="required input_field"><label for="lokasi[]">Lokasi: </label><input type="text" name="lokasi[]" id="lokasi[]"  class="required input_field"><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
```

Comment: so only close the <label> tag? @Naveen

Comment: the database only accepted the last data input,why? @NaveenSinghraghuvanshi

Comment: yes label tag should be closed because if wont be then tree will be like this

`div>label>label>remove_button` but if you close it tree will be like that `div>remove_button` so div will be parent of that button

Comment: can u provide me more info

Comment: the database only accept the data from the last input field, lets day the user add 3 input field, i want all 3 of the data be inserted in the databse. @ NaveenSinghraghuvanshi

Comment: how you put the inputs to database because i can't see here your code u can add new question for that one else this code is fine. People may help you

Answer (score 0):

PFB code , hope it helps . The problem i feel was you were binding click event for remove on document.ready so at that point of time that anchor for remove was not created as it's being created on add , so click event was not getting binded. Have binded it on add handler.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ var max_fields = 25; var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); var add_button = $(".add_field_button");

    var x = 1; //initial text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><label for="no_telefon">No.Telefon: <input type="text" name="no_telefon[]" id="no_telefon[]" class="required input_field"><label for="lokasi[]">Lokasi: <input type="text" name="lokasi[]" id="lokasi[]"  class="required input_field"><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }

        $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent().parent().remove(); x--;
    });
    });


});
```